# Adding custom image as separator in wordpress footer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to add custom separator image in wordpress footer, here is my functions.php code:

```
function advertica_lite_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Page Sidebar',
    'id' => 'page-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="ske-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="ske-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Blog Sidebar',
    'id' => 'blog-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="ske-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="ske-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Footer Sidebar',
    'id' => 'footer-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="ske-footer-container span3 ske-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="ske-title ske-footer-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));  }
```

I want to add image as separator between all 3 blocks, i tried couple of google help but didn't got any help relevant to what i was looking for. Would there be anyone who can assist me the modification ?

i want it something like this:

[image]

Comment: At where to add image ,, Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @devilcrab would you please share your link? So I will better way to check this issue.

Comment: Guys check out i have added image i want it the way you see above, where WIDGET 1,2,3 are default code available in theme base but i want to add horizontal bar which i have ready in png format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.ske-container{
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 0px 5px;
 width:30%;
 float:left;
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vmnN.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;  
}
.ske-container:last-child{
 background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ske-container">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <div class="ske-container">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <div class="ske-container">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```

Would you please add above `CSS` in your current theme `style.css`? And check it.

Comment: @devilcrab It's simply you can remove `.ske-container:last-child` CSS.

Comment: i already removed this " .ske-container:last-child{
 background-image: none; }" but still its displaying that's why i asked

Comment: @devilcrab Have you try this `.ske-container:last-child{ background-image: none !important;}` ?

Comment: @devilcrab Would you please provide me your link? So I can better way to check this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132175/discussion-between-purvik7373-and-devilcrab).